# Accessing images with Instant Apps or App Clips

Tags: android, ios, android-instant-apps, apple-appclips

I am building an app that will upload images/photos from mobile device to cloud storage. But to do this I want to avoid installation as much as possible. I looked up and found Instant Apps /App clips might be the solution for Android / iOS. But with instant apps/app clips it is not clear to me if I can access images and also upload images to cloud storage.

Can someone point me to documentation / example that can help me do clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding iOS: you can't access user Photos.

Please check this doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/choosing_the_right_functionality_for_your_app_clip

> App Clips also come with limitations that help protect user data. They
> **can’t access**:
>
> - Apple Music and Media
> - Data from apps like Calendar, Contacts, Files, Health, Messages,
>   Reminders, and **Photos**
> - Motion and fitness data